# Sticky Sidebar with parent Div

Tags: html, css

I know there are similar questions but I can't seem to implement the answers successfully so i'd thought i'd ask to try get an answer for my context.

I'm trying to keep a div with class `.product-info` fixed on the screen as you scroll down the page, with in it's parent div (`.product-info-container`). Once the fixed div reaches the bottom of the parent it should stop, i've tried using `position:fixed` but it fixes the div to the window, not the parent div.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```css
/* Container */

.product-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.product-introduction {
  height: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
  width: 70vw;
  min-width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.product-image-grid {
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.image-container {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.image-container.small {
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  height: 500px
}

.Product-Image {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container.large {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 1000px;
}

.product-info-container {
  height: 1500px;
  min-height: calc(10vh - 140px);
  width: calc(550px - 25px);
  min-width: calc(550px - 25px);
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.product-info {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  width: calc(550px - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
}

h1.product-title {
  font-family: "Magistral_Bold";
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.intro-feature-icon {
  width: 150px;
}

.intro-feature-icon:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.intro-feature-icon:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;
}

.price-bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: unset;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.price-bar h2 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.currency-selector {
  color: #919191;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.currency-selector.selected {
  color: black !important;
}

.currency-selector:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wtb-cta {
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <div class="product-introduction">

    <div class="product-image-grid">
      <div class="image-container small">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-1.png" alt="Test Image 1" class="Product-Image One">
      </div>
      <div class="image-container small">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-2.png" alt="Test Image 2" class="Product-Image Two">
      </div>
      <div class="image-container large">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-3.png" alt="Test Image 3" class="Product-Image Three">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-info-container">
      <div class="product-info">
        <h1 class="product-title no-shadow">Hinterland</h1>
        <h4 class="h4-black no-shadow">DRY2DRY&trade; TRI-LAMINATE JACKET</h4>

        <div class="icon-bar">
          <img src="Images/02-Icons/Tech-Icons/Materials/TriLaminate/TriLaminateD2D-square-black.png" alt="Tri Laminate Logo" class="intro-feature-icon">
          <img src="Images/02-Icons/Tech-Icons/CE-Icons/ce-approved.png" alt="CE Approved Logo" class="intro-feature-icon">
        </div>

        <p class="black no-shadow">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis velit aperiam soluta maiores fugiat facere dolorum obcaecati, repellat commodi eveniet deserunt doloribus, esse magnam alias qui eos officia reprehenderit? Dolorum.
        </p>

        <div class="price-bar">
          <h2 class="h2-min black no-shadow">£299.99</h2>
          <p class="currency-selector no-shadow selected"> £ </p>
          <p class="currency-selector no-shadow "> $ </p>
        </div>

        <a href="#">
          <div class="wtb-cta">
            <h3>WHERE TO BUY</h2>
          </div>
        </a>

        <button class="accordion">
           <h3 class="black no-shadow">DESCRIPTION</h3>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p class="no-shadow black">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">
           <h3 class="black no-shadow">ADDITIONAL INFO</h3>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p class="no-shadow black">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which div u want to be fixed at the top of the parent ?

Comment: Yes, untill it reaches the bottom then it stops scrolling.

Comment: u have lot of divs in u r code which div u want to be fixed ?

Comment: The div ".product-info" should be fixed within .product-info-container

Comment: do want to keep the right side div(.product-info) to be fixed until  the page reaches the bottom i'm right ?

Comment: Yes. I want there to be more content underneath this section, once it reaches that it should stop, and not overlap that

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're trying to achieve but I think you might be looking for position:sticky ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting.

Add `position:sticky` and `top:0` to .product-info class.

```
.product-info {
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  height: auto;
  width: calc(550px - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```css
/* Container */

.product-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.product-introduction {
  height: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
  width: 70vw;
  min-width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.product-image-grid {
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.image-container {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.image-container.small {
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  height: 500px
}

.Product-Image {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container.large {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 1000px;
}

.product-info-container {
  height: 1500px;
  min-height: calc(10vh - 140px);
  width: calc(550px - 25px);
  min-width: calc(550px - 25px);
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.product-info {
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  height: auto;
  width: calc(550px - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
}

h1.product-title {
  font-family: "Magistral_Bold";
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.intro-feature-icon {
  width: 150px;
}

.intro-feature-icon:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.intro-feature-icon:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;
}

.price-bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: unset;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.price-bar h2 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.currency-selector {
  color: #919191;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.currency-selector.selected {
  color: black !important;
}

.currency-selector:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.wtb-cta {
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-wrapper">
  <div class="product-introduction">

    <div class="product-image-grid">
      <div class="image-container small">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-1.png" alt="Test Image 1" class="Product-Image One">
      </div>
      <div class="image-container small">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-2.png" alt="Test Image 2" class="Product-Image Two">
      </div>
      <div class="image-container large">
        <img src="Images/01-Product-Images/Test-image-3.png" alt="Test Image 3" class="Product-Image Three">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-info-container">
      <div class="product-info">
        <h1 class="product-title no-shadow">Hinterland</h1>
        <h4 class="h4-black no-shadow">DRY2DRY&trade; TRI-LAMINATE JACKET</h4>

        <div class="icon-bar">
          <img src="Images/02-Icons/Tech-Icons/Materials/TriLaminate/TriLaminateD2D-square-black.png" alt="Tri Laminate Logo" class="intro-feature-icon">
          <img src="Images/02-Icons/Tech-Icons/CE-Icons/ce-approved.png" alt="CE Approved Logo" class="intro-feature-icon">
        </div>

        <p class="black no-shadow">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis velit aperiam soluta maiores fugiat facere dolorum obcaecati, repellat commodi eveniet deserunt doloribus, esse magnam alias qui eos officia reprehenderit? Dolorum.
        </p>

        <div class="price-bar">
          <h2 class="h2-min black no-shadow">£299.99</h2>
          <p class="currency-selector no-shadow selected"> £ </p>
          <p class="currency-selector no-shadow "> $ </p>
        </div>

        <a href="#">
          <div class="wtb-cta">
            <h3>WHERE TO BUY</h2>
          </div>
        </a>

        <button class="accordion">
           <h3 class="black no-shadow">DESCRIPTION</h3>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p class="no-shadow black">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">
           <h3 class="black no-shadow">ADDITIONAL INFO</h3>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p class="no-shadow black">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```